# how to write DATE_FORMAT(now(), "%m/%d/%Y") in django raw query

Tags: mysql, django

how to write this query in django orm or django raw query

```
SELECT *  FROM rfq_db.RFQapp_rfq where quotes_due >= DATE_FORMAT(now(), "%m/%d/%Y") GROUP BY rfq_id  order by quotes_due desc;
```

Comment: please show sample table data @dilip kumar

Comment: You can't compare dates in that form, they're not sortable. Why are you doing it that way? Use [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), `YYYY-MM-DD`, the MySQL default, if you need to compare. With your approach Feb 1, 2020 comes after Jan 1, 2030.